# How to incorporate voltage controlled current limitation

Tags: current-limiting

This is part of a lab PSU and programmable load, for generic lab use including e.g. battery charging/discharging. This question is about the desgin of the current limiter in the psu part.

It must be controllable from a computer. This part will be achieved with an arduino and/or raspberry pi inside the device.
The current limitation could be implemented in software, but I don't trust this to react fast enough.

I have seen many designs that use potentiometers to adjust the current limit, but I want to use the microcontroller gpio/dac outputs to set reference voltages that control the output voltage and current limit.

My idea so far is based mainly on opamps. The voltage regulation is simple enough with a voltage follower with some current amplification, e.g.:

[image]

I'm thinking the current could be limited by manipulating either the feedback line or the Vref line, based on sensing the current with a shunt resistor. However, my attempts at this all sort of feel unnecessarily complicated.

Not sure if there is any rationality behind this, but it also bothers me that the output has a different ground than the internal circuitry. Should I care?

[image]

Attempts at addressing the different ground levels issue
(Would these even work?)
[image] [image]

I'm sure this can be achieved simpler and more elegantly, probably by using more suitable techniquies and principles. I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Get a simulator and simulate the circuit. Micro-cap (full version) is now free and it is awesome.

Comment: You may be overthinking it a bit...an NPN with an emitter resistor to ground makes a fine voltage controlled current source.  Drive it with an op amp with the negative input coming from the emitter to improve accuracy and zero-base the input.

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen used in lab supplies use is a voltage regulator circuit where the current limiting is done by "pulling down" the Vref when too much current is flowing. Similar to your 2nd schematic but the current limiting circuit needs to pull on the Vref, not the feedback, I have drawn a quick schematic of what I mean:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL3ggA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

OA1, Q1, R1 and R2 are a basic voltage regulator, multiplying Vref with a factor 10 at the output. So 0 - 3 V gives 0 - 30 V.

When the current exceeds the value set at V_Iref, the output of OA2 will go **low** and via D1 the input voltage of the voltage regulator is decreased. That should limit the current to the point where OA2 "flips back" and V(Rshunt) = V_Iref.

The diode is crucial. Suppose the current through the load is **lower** than the value set by V_Iref. Then the output of OA2 is **high**. That would **pull up** the reference voltage and make the output **increase the output voltage** until the set current is reached. You don't want that, you want the voltage to be maximized by the voltage regulation loop, not the current regulation loop. The diode makes sure the current regulation loop can only regulate **down** and not up.

This circuit still needs some feedback resistors around OA2 so that it will behave like an amplifier and not like a comparator like it does now.